# Covering code in main function with unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, go

Golang show that I have only 50% of covering code, and as I see code in main is not covered, I've tried to search but not found anything with explanations how to cover code in main.

**main.go**

```
package main

func Sum(x int, y int) int {
    return x + y
}

func main() {
    Sum(5, 5)
}
```

**main_test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSum(t *testing.T) {
    total := Sum(5, 5)
    if total != 10 {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's generally best to keep the code in the `main` package and `main()` function minimal so that testing is unnecessary; basically, the only code in `main` should be calling into the entry point in another package (which can then be covered by tests as needed).

Comment: Don't update your question with the answer--just accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test files usually are directly next to the code they test. Depending on the size of your project you don't have to extract your sum function into another package just to test it and it also doesn't have to be public:

**main.go**

```
package main

func main() {
    sum()
}

func sum() int {
    return 5 + 5
}
```

**main_test.go**:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestSum(t *testing.T) {
    total := sum()
    if total != 10 {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing here is if you run `go test -cover` for that code you will get: ```coverage: 50.0% of statements ```